# Scheduling a function to run at certain time of the day for a period of time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to schedule a function to run at certain times of the day for lets say 10:30 am and also repeat it every 2 seconds for 1 minute and then sleep until its called again at the next scheduled time.

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")


schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

schedule.every().day.at("10:45").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am open to using other modules also
Windows Operating system

the code above is an example, ideally a certain function will be scheduled, not the entire coding.

Comment: what are the issues with your current approach?

Comment: Please mention the OS. On Linux distro's this is easy with `cron`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the current method would only execute the function once and then wait for 10:45 to execute it again.

Comment: If you do it with the schedule module than you need to keep the process alive 24/7 in order for it to work. This is essentially what services are for. But creating a service in python for windows isn't that trivial.
Instead i think it would be better to use the [windows task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).